# MFC How to make ctreectrl virtual?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, treeview, treecontrol

My application is displaying a Hugh amount of files system entries held in memory using a `ctreectrl` , adding all the items takes ~20seconds even when using `SetRedraw(False)` , so how to make a completely virtual(breadth,depth) `ctreectrl` & how to populate it ?

Edit#1
I want to display the displayed portion items expanded from the beginning , but I don't want to store them in the tree, for example

```
Root-->
    Child1-->
        SubChile1
    Child2
    Child3
```

Comment: *treeview* can not be virtual like *listview* because it not plain, but have complex structure. so message like `LVM_SETITEMCOUNT` is not enough for tree. you need direct add every item. `I don't want to store them in the tree` - so it and will be not in tree and will be not shown anyway - you have no choice. but you can "smart" add items - not all at once but visible only. and expand it by request. and not store say name in item but use `I_*CALLBACK` and handle `TVN_GETDISPINFO`

Answer (score 3):

you must not add all items at once. you must add only top level items with `cChildren = I_CHILDRENCALLBACK`
and handle `WM_NOTIFY`

- with `code == TVN_GETDISPINFO` if `mask & TVIF_CHILDREN` set
  `cChildren` (TRUE or FALSE)
- with `code == TVN_ITEMEXPANDING`, `action == TVE_EXPAND` - expand
  node - add only **direct** child items (one level) again with
  `cChildren = I_CHILDRENCALLBACK`

and possible

- with `code == TVN_ITEMEXPANDED`, `action == TVE_COLLAPSE` - collapse
  node - remove **all** childs

---

sense of `cChildren = I_CHILDRENCALLBACK` - if you add folder to list, you not need at once initialize it (open handle, enum childs) - only when you first time got `I_CHILDRENCALLBACK` (this when your item become visible, but if containing folder large enough(like *system32*) - it have too many items, but visible only several top at begin, new begin visible when user scroll down)- open folder, determinate are it have subitems (and based on this set `cChildren`) but not full enumerate it (do this only on `<TVN_ITEMEXPANDING, TVE_EXPAND>`

Answer (score 2):

I have no advice to make it virtual.
I use for large tree structures the possibility of collecting a child branch only when it is need. I trap [TVN_ITEMEXPANDING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

So how to do it: First read the first level (root), than keep all root node collapsed and read all child nodes of the root (just 1 level deep) and populate them.

When a node expands, you already have the nodes, now read the next level below the childs of the expanding node.

So you see only the expanded nodes plus one invisible level.

I do this in this way to show all nodes that are expandable with the + sign. All nodes without children nodes are shown without it as leafs.

The second way is not to fill the string data and let the tree load it via callback. But the impact is small. The real problem with the speed are the number of nodes.